# How to get the value from array of Objects in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to get the firstname from the array of Objects where my code is like

```
$scope.value=JSON.stringify(myData);
```

Output for $scope.value is like this,

```
[{"firstname":"Swag","lastname":"Dear"}]
```

I need to retrieve `$scope.value[0].firstname` but I am not able to get the record. Please let me know how to get the record.

Comment: Do not `JSON.stringify` it.

Comment: Why are you using `stringify()`? This serializes your array<object> to a JSON string,  which prevents you from getting the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you stringify the value it becomes long json string with all the values. Iterating on the json object will give you the respective values.

```
$scope.value=myData;
  for(var x;x < $scope.value.length;x++){
     console.log($scope.value[i].firstname);
     //do something 
  }
```

Comment: I can able to get the value, thanks for your suggestion but I am not able to assign the value to another scope value and I am getting "cannot read property of 0  error" but if I try to view the data it is displaying from console.log($scope.value[0].firstname)
If I try to assign using $scope.firstname=$scope.value[0].firstname; like this and it is not working. 
Please suggest I need to assign it to a value.

Comment: paste your html please, try to use ng-repeat to get your values directly from $scope.value